# What should I do to get better FPS in gameplay

Tags: windows-8, gaming, fps

This happens with *all* games, not just one or two. Most are launched through Steam but not all.

When I play a game, there's always a bit of lag between when I press a key/move my mouse/etc. I'd say something around 0.5-1 second.

My computer specifications:

> 8GB RAM
>
> 3.1GHz i5 Processor
>
> Windows 8 Pro 64-Bit
>
> [1024MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 6450 Graphics card](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/amd-radeon-hd-6000/hd-6450/Pages/amd-radeon-hd-6450-overview.aspx)
>
> 7200RPM 500GB Hard-Drive

Even running at the lowest settings I get this lag. It's even on menus (when I hover my mouse over something there's a delay).

What could be causing this? How should I fix it?

Unplugging my second monitor helps a *teeny* bit, however it's so little I think it may just be a placebo effect. I usually only have skype up on my second monitor so it's not doing anything complex.

With anything else resource-intensive, my computer is *great*. It's only games that have this delay.

Whenever I run the auto-setup in games I almost *always* get the best graphics settings, or something near them.

Comment: I would check your temps, make sure they are staying around 40-50c if not things may be over heating IE your video card, or processor or both... Also, Defrag your HD...You might be surprised how much this might help

Comment: The computer doesn't know you're playing games, so it's not 'only games'.  :)  You've listed _nothing_ that you've tried, aside from unplugging a monitor.  Drivers up to date?  Does reinstalling Windows help? Disks checked? Performance monitor or Resource Monitor show anything?

Comment: @techie007 All drivers are up-to-date, I've re-installed windows, discs have been checked, and I don't know what I'd do with resource monitor.

Comment: Why wouldn't you put that in your original question?  Anything else you'd like us to ask you so you can tell us you tried it already? ;)  Search: PerfMon.

Comment: That's a so-so graphics card, not really designed for heavy gaming.  (Hint: ATI says it's for "everyday computing".)  The first thing you need to do is to get a better card (or two). Is your keyboard and/or mouse wireless?  How fast is your internet connection?

Comment: @Debra They're wireless but instantly responsive on anything else. It happens even when I'm offline gaming. And is there a graphics cards (For ~$100) you would recommend I should get if it is that?

Comment: @techie007 What should I monitor on process monitor?

Comment: Not ProcMon, PerfMon. :) Performance Monitor... it's built into Windows...  So's the Resource Monitor.

Comment: Get the best graphics card you can afford that will work in your system.  While all fundamental components are critical to gaming, the graphics card is the #1 issue when you suffer poor fps & other performance issues. I can't really recommend anything specific, but the serious gamers that I know spend many hundreds on the graphics card alone. So spend what seems appropriate to your desire to use it for gaming. As for the wireless mouse & kbd, the responses in games are more critical & wireless will often cause visible lags.

Comment: You're seeing this even with games that are not graphics intense?  Even with 2D platformers or similar titles?  And is your question about low FPS or is it about laggy input?

Comment: You don't even mention what framerates you're actually getting. Does the screen actually look jittery, like there is a low frame rate? The time between pressing a button and seeing the result on your screen may have very little to do with framerates. Some displays (mainly TVs, but some others) have many filters that they push the image through which causes lag between when a frame is sent to the TV, and when it's displayed.  TVs often have a "Game Mode" to remove filters and fix some of the problems. Additional latencies can also be introduced by things such as keyboards and mice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

low FPS come from your SLOW Graphic card. The 6450 is only useful for office work.

Get at least a [HD 78xx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_7000_Series#Southern_Islands_.28HD_7xxx.29_Series) to have a really good gaming card.

Comment: Have you ever heard about GPU overclocking??

Comment: @Jet GPU overclocking is at best a potentially marginal improvement and at worst actively harmful. It is not the end solution to a terminally slow graphics card unless you want emphasis on the "terminal" part.

Comment: @Mokubai If everything's OK with GPU temperature (I mean if you have good coolers), and you don't overclock to the maximum , then it will not be so harmful. A lot of people do it. For example, 20% overclocking is not harmful for most videocards.

Comment: @Jet Mokubai is right, the card is so slow, that OC make NO sense at all!

Answer (score 0):

Many people think there are no ways to increase videocard performance. But it's false.
There are some ways to do it:

1. If you close all odd programs, processes, tasks, then you'll see some increase of performance. There are some tools that do it pretty well. My favourite is [**Razer Game Booster**](http://www.razerzone.com/gamebooster).
2. You can see higher FPSes if you use your CPU for graphics too! For example, using [**SwiftShader**](http://transgaming.com/swiftshader) will really boost your games (I use it, and I really see good FPS increase)!
3. Update your video drivers and other videocard programs.
4. Overclocking is the best option. You can make your GPU really faster  by changing its power options! But in that case you will need better coolers, because your GPU will become hot.
   True overclocks can increase performance of GPU by 20%, 50% and maybe more. To find how to overclock your graphics card, just google "[**Overclock Radeon HD 6450**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Radeon%20hd%206450%20overclock)".

So, you can live with your old videocard more than expected !)

---

**NOTE:** You can combine all these options. They have no conflicts.